# Distinct in linq?

Tags: c#, linq, distinct

I am wondering how can I achieve this?

I want to get only distinct names from a collection of objects

```
MyObject a = new Object();
a.Name = 'One';
a.Value = '10';


MyObject b = new Object();
b.Name = 'One';
b.Value = '15';


MyObject c = new Object();
c.Name = 'Two';
c.Value = '10';
```

So I want to get only back the name. I don't care about the value in this case just the name.

So I tried

//add all the objects to a collection.

```
myCollection.Disinct()..Select(x => new MyClassToStore() {Text = x.Name, Value = x.Name}).ToList());
```

However I need to do distinct at the property level not at the object level. So I want back "One" and "Two". Right now I get "One", "One" and "Two" back.

I see a library called [morelinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/)  but I not sure if I should use it as it still in beta and does not seem to be developed on anymore.

Plus a whole library for one extract query I am not sure if it is worth it.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489258/linq-distinct-on-a-particular-property

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This populates both the Text and Value fields:

```
   myCollection.Select(x => x.Name).Distinct()
      .Select(x => new MyClassToStore { Text = x, Value = x }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 23):

Maybe something like this can help?

```
var distinctItems = items
     .GroupBy(x => x.PropertyToCompare)
     .Select(x => x.First());
```

Comment: how could I get stick it into MyClassToStore

Comment: var distinctitems = myCollection.GroupBy(x => x.Name).Select(x => x.First()).Select(new MyClassToStore() {Text = x.Name, Value = x.Name}) i suppose, altough i did not get exactly what you need. because using the same property (name) twice is a bit awkward... I think that you should listen to Cameron if you need just names...

Answer (score 6):

If you just want back distinct names, you can use:

```
myCollection.Select(x => x.Name).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can implement your class so the linq distinct operator does not use the default equality comparer.

```
class YourClass:IEquatable<YourClass> 
{
```

... Your implementation details.   ...

```
    public bool Equals(YourClass other)
    {
        if (Object.Equals(this, other))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            if(Name == other.Name && Value == other.Value)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

 public override int GetHashCode()
 {
     return Name.GetHashCode() ^ Value.GetHashCode();
 }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally I suggest you override operator == and != and determine how and why an object is unique there.  Then use the Distinct() call on the collection.

You do have to be careful with null values, see Microsoft's [Guidelines for Overloading Equals() and Operator == (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: To be clear, do not override the `==` or `!=` operator in any sort of global context. What's suggested here is to override the `Equals` and `==` operator your class inherits from `object`