# Get single value list of Company Codes for Combobox

Tags: c#, linq, combobox

I have a logging table that lists all of the updates our customers receives. In the column, the company code can be listed several times. I need to get a list of all available codes in the list but only show them once.

Here is my column:

[image]

I'd like to query the column and only return:

```
DEM
FRK
```

And not:

```
DEM
DEM
DEM
FRK
```

I can query the list as such:

```
private void PopulateCompanyCodes()
{
  var entity = new SuburbanWebServiceEntities();
  var qry = from x in entity.UpdateLogs
            select x.CompanyCode;

  comboBox_CompanyCodes.Items.Add(string.Empty);
  foreach (var cc in qry.ToList())
  {
    comboBox_CompanyCodes.Items.Add(cc);
  }
  comboBox_CompanyCodes.Text = string.Empty;
}
```

But of course, I'm getting DEM listed several times:

[image]

Is there a way to get the first list, only showing each item once for a combobox?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to use Distinct for that
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608127/distinct-in-linq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried doing it like this. Using Distinct gets rid of duplicates.

```
foreach (var cc in qry.Distinct().ToList())
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Distinct`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348436(v=vs.100).aspx). You'll have to switch to [method syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx) but that's no big deal.

```
var qry = entity.UpdateLogs.Select(l => l.CompanyCode).Distinct();

comboBox_CompanyCodes.Items.Add(string.Empty);
foreach (var cc in qry.ToList())
{
    comboBox_CompanyCodes.Items.Add(cc);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use group by:

```
var qry = entity.UpdateLogs.GroupBy(l => l.CompanyCode);
```